# saving Textbox values for next time I run an application

Tags: c#, forms, textbox, save

I have a form with 30 text boxes which contain default setting I set in my code. the user has an option to change it , but I want to know how can I save the new values chosen by the user in one (or more) of those text boxes for next time I run the application.
thanks a lot

Comment: Use a config file, and save the changes on it

Comment: You can save it in a text-file or xml-file or a database..... Any own first attempts?

Comment: There are many ways: store them is a DB, the built-in config file, your own xml/json file...

Comment: do you want to be able to change the values in the file by hand?

Comment: I want to be able to change a textbox value manually and then save this change to next time I open the app

Comment: @apomene , can you please show me how to do it? (new to this)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about editing your saved file and don't intend to rename the textboxes or change the layout of them you can leave the ordering of values to the compiler. Use this for saving:

```
// first collect all values
List<string> allvalues = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Select(x => x.Text).ToList();
// write to file
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("yourPath", String.Join(Environment.NewLine, allvalues));
```

and this for loading:

```
//load the values:
string [] alllines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("yourPath");

List<TextBox> allTextboxes = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < allTextboxes.Count; i++)
{
    allTextboxes[i].Text = alllines[i];
}
```

Explanation:

`this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()` gets you all controls that are textboxes in your windows form.

`String.Join(Environment.NewLine, allvalues)` combines all values to a string separated by a newline.

Comment: thank you very much! may I ask how to do it with config file?

Comment: @MongZhu: Good format of answering with explanation.

Answer (score 2):

the app.config is an XML file with many predefined configuration sections available and support for custom configuration sections. An example where we have a tag for setting Name `mySetting` and `mySetting2` is shown

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>  
     <appSettings>    
    <add key="mySetting" value="myValue1"/>
    <add key="mySetting2" value="myValue12" />  
  </appSettings>
    </configuration>
```

In order to use config files you must add a reference to `System.Configuration`, so you can  use  `ConfigurationManager` class. Below is a sample for reading and writing to `app.config` file:

**WRITE TO CONFIG From TEXTBOX:**

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.AppSettings.Settings["mySetting"].Value=textBox1.Text;
config.Save();
```

**READ from Config:**

```
 var mySetting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mySetting"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to solve this problem:

```
//To write textbox values to file (may be used on form close)
using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("values.txt"))
{
    foreach (var control in this.Controls)
    {
        if (control is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox txt = (TextBox)control;
            sw.WriteLine(txt.Name + ":" + txt.Text);
        }
    }
}


//To read textbox values from file (may be used on form load)
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("values.txt"))
{
    string line = "";
    while((line=sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        //Ugly, but work in every case
        string control = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(':') );
        string val =  line.Substring(line.IndexOf(':') + 1);

        if(this.Controls[control] != null)
        {
            ((TextBox)this.Controls[control]).Text = val;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save values in file. For 30 text field you can use 30 lines or just comma separated values.

When user change the value then write new values in that file, so on next startup you will have new values in file and each time don't have to read old data.

Comment: This answer probably needs a little more elaboration. Maybe some code examples of *how* to save/load the text to/from a file and *where* to do it, rather than just a high-level explanation; otherwise this has already been suggested in comments. HTH